# Azure Linux Web App not compressing files for dotnet core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I'm investigating load times for my Angular app built in dotnet core 3.1 hosted on a Azure Linux web app and have noticed that the javascript files are not compressed:

[image]

I've read that by default Azure Web Apps should compress responses and I shouldn't have to do anything to enable this. However, as I am running Kestrel I don't think I can take advantage of server compression, is that correct?

If I can't use server compression I can use [Response Compression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-3.1), but wanted to check that this is the correct course of action? As the javascript files I'm mostly interested in are mostly static, would this middleware be compressing them every time or would it cache them?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand what effect you want to achieve. But I think the part of this article about dotnet core project to compress .js and .css files should be useful to you. https://www.davidhayden.me/blog/asp-net-core-bundle-and-minify-css-and-js